# how to compose mail when button at index clicked in UIActionSheet?

Tags: ios, iphone, email, uiactionsheet, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am a bit confused on how to display mail composer when I click the email option in `UIActionSheet`.
Here's my sample code:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        NSString *emailTitle = @"Test Email";
        NSString *messageBody = @"iOS programming is so fun!";
        NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"support@email.com"];
        MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
        [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
        [mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];
        [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: Is the UIViewController embedded in a UINavigationController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you add to your .h file and import the MessageUI.framework

Here is exactly what your looking for. I use this often. By the way UIActionSheets are deprecated in iOS 8. Here you go though:

.h

```
ViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

.m

```
- (IBAction)showActionSheet:(id)sender {

UIActionSheet *moreActions = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Add To Favorites", @"Search",@"Email", nil];
[moreActions showInView:self.view];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

switch (buttonIndex) {
    case 0: [self addToFav:self];
        break;
    case 1: ; [self popSearchBar:self];
        break;
    case 2: { [self sendEmail];
        break;
    }
        break;
}
}
- (void)sendEmail {
NSString *emailTitle = @"This is email title";
// Email Content as for HTML
NSString *messageBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I may have found a missing document in your catalog. I tried opening :<p><strong><font color=\"red\"> %@ </font><br>'%@'</strong></p> with no results. Can I have a dollar for reporting this?", self.title, self.titleString];
// To address
NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"youremail@google.com"];

MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mc setSubject:emailTitle];
[mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:YES];
[mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

// Present mail view controller on screen
[self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
 - (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult: (MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
switch (result)
{
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        NSLog(@"Mail saved");
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        NSLog(@"Mail sent");
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
// Close the Mail Interface
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Also note that some people are having issues with simulator emails. try it on a device before you give up.

Comment: Thanx for ur time, but actually what jam facing is tat i have uiactionsheet which display two option called Email,Gmail. when i click email option in action sheet i need to get email page with from and to recipients –

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for @Anandios can you be more specific

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code:

First add and import the message framework:

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
```

then mark your self as a delegate like this

```
@interface MYViewController () <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

then to pull up the composer:

```
- (IBAction)emailButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        MFMailComposeViewController *composeViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [composeViewController setMailComposeDelegate:self];
        [composeViewController setToRecipients:@[@"example@email.com"]];
        [composeViewController setSubject:@"example subject"];
        [self presentViewController:composeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Then to handle the delegate callback and dismiss the composer:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    //Add an alert in case of failure
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

in actionsheet using `actionSheet: clickedButtonAtIndex:`

```
    - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    //Get the name of the current pressed button
    NSString *buttonTitle = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if  ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Your button title"]) {
        [self btnContact];
    }

}
```

call this method

```
- (void)btnContact{
    // Email Subject
    NSString *emailTitle = @"";
    // Email Content
    NSString *messageBody = @"";
    // To address
    NSString *toRecp = @"";
    NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:toRecp];

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
    [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
    [mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

    // Present mail view controller on screen
    [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Thanx for ur time, but actually what jam facing is tat i have uiactionsheet which display two option called Email,Gmail. when i click email option in action sheet i need to get email page with from and to recipients

Comment: i getting this response in log : 2014-12-04 18:41:58.020 AmslideMenu[5968:607] Warning: Attempt to present <MFMailComposeViewController: 0xbba82b0> on <UINavigationController: 0xb9391b0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
\

Answer (score 0):

This is appcoda's code . Instead of index use the button's name to fire your mail option .