# Saving a text from UIAlertView

Tags: save, uialertview, textfield

I have written a `UIAlertView` code with a `textField` and I want to write a code to store whatever is typed by the user as a pushable detail list. How can I do that?

```
- (IBAction)NewReference:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *newreference = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Reference" message:@"Enter Name" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: @"Done",nil];
    newreference.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [newreference textFieldAtIndex:0].delegate = self;
    [newreference show];
}
```

Comment: Where are your storing it and how?

Comment: I want to store it in the app??i'm thinking of using NSUserDefaults...

Comment: yeah duh!? ha 
I guess i have to spell it all out for you:

Where do you want to 'store' it? 
Are you storing it in Core Data, or plist, or txt file, or sqlite, or a server or backend etc etc.

How are you displaying it? 
Tableview, cell.textLabel, UILabel, UIButton title etc etc

You have to be more clear than what you offered for people to help you out, thats probably why you don't have any answers yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go good sir. Per your comment above, if you want to store data for NSUserDefaults here is how you would do it:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString* saveData = [[newreference textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
[defaults setObject:saveData forKey:@"whatever key you want here"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Then to invoke or call it:

```
NSString* recallData = [defaults objectForKey:@"whatever key you named above"];
```

Happy coding -

Comment: Sorry I'm new to objective C... I want to store it as a core data or plist... And I want to display it as a table view or UI button title...

Comment: Okay. It's no problem. There are numerous tutorials out there explaining what you want. Google saving data to plist and then Google populate UITableView from plist you'll be just fine. It would be redundant had I typed it all out for you. Sometimes the best thing to do is learn how to do it yourself or else you won't get anywhere

Comment: hey, I'm trying to setup send email from my app..problem i have is it only copies the subject, it doesn't copy the email or message body.. can you help? here's the code I'm using at the moment.                                [mailComposer setToRecipients:emailaddress];
[mailComposer setSubject:sendSubject];
[mailComposer setMessageBody:sendMessage isHTML:NO];

Comment: I have also declared an Array for the email and strings for the subj and message body......   NSArray *emailaddress;
    emailaddress = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"kaikaiy@uni.coventry.ac.uk", nil];
    
    //get string for subject and message
    NSString *sendSubject = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",self.Subject.text];
    NSString *sendMessage = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",self.Message.text];

Comment: hey @YasminKaikai see my answer below for help on that matter. I would suggest looking at apple documentation though, not everyone is going to help you code every little bit of your app for you, and don't forget there are tutorials already out there, you just have to go find them okay! :) Please note at the very bottom i mention some people are having issues seeing content of emails in the simulator, try on a physical device:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293356/how-to-compose-mail-when-button-at-index-clicked-in-uiactionsheet/27293554#27293554